# How to run string math expression in SQL Server (trigger or function)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016

I want to run:

```
 select Mycalculatefunction('((3*4)-3)*5') 
 select ('((3*4)-3)*5')
```

OUTPUT: `((3*4)-3)*5`  wrong (not int value)

My desired output is: 45

I defined a stored procedure:

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.Eval
    (@exp varchar(MAX))
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @SQLString NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @SQLString = 'SELECT '+@exp

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQLString
```

I call it:

```
exec dbo.Eval '((3*4)-3)*5'
```

How can I do in this process is the trigger?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SP is vulnerable to injection. F.e. I pass `exec dbo.Eval '1;DROP TABLE some_table;'`. Better use xml.[query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191474.aspx):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Eval 
    @formula nvarchar(max)
AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = N'
DECLARE @x xml = ''''
SELECT CAST(@x.query('''+@formula+''') as nvarchar(max))'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Then

```
EXEC dbo.Eval '((3*4)-3)*5'
```

Output:

```
45
```

Triggers part (as there were no info about your tables, just general explanation, I add full batch with comments):

```
--Create table that will store Formulas
CREATE TABLE Formulas (
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    Formula nvarchar(max) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_ID PRIMARY KEY (ID)
) 
GO
--Create table to store results of the formulas
CREATE TABLE Results (
    T1_ID int NOT NULL,
    Result int NULL
) 
GO
--Linked by ID
ALTER TABLE Results ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Formulas_Results FOREIGN KEY (T1_ID)
REFERENCES Formulas (ID)
GO
--Create a Table Valued Parameter
CREATE TYPE FormulaResults AS TABLE ( 
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Formula nvarchar(max) NULL
)
GO
--Create a procedure to do the count
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetResults 
    @TVP FormulaResults READONLY
AS
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @sql = N'DECLARE @x xml = '''' '

SELECT @sql = @sql + 'SELECT '+CAST(ID as nvarchar(max))+' as ID, CAST(@x.query('''+Formula+''') as nvarchar(max)) UNION ALL '
FROM @TVP

SELECT @sql = LEFT(@sql,LEN(@sql)-LEN('UNION ALL '))

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
GO
--Create a trigger that will count formula after insert and update
CREATE TRIGGER GetResultsTrigger
ON Formulas
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
DECLARE @FormulaTVP AS FormulaResults
DECLARE @Results TABLE(
    T1_ID int NOT NULL,
    Result int NULL
) 


INSERT INTO @FormulaTVP
SELECT *
FROM inserted

INSERT INTO @Results
EXEC dbo.GetResults @FormulaTVP

MERGE Results r
USING @Results s
ON r.T1_ID = s.T1_ID
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES (s.T1_ID, s.Result)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET Result = s.Result;
```

After that run:

```
INSERT INTO [Formulas] VALUES
('1+3'),('2+2*8')


SELECT  [ID],
        [Formula]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Formulas]

SELECT [T1_ID],
        [Result]
FROM [Test].[dbo].[Results]
```

Output:

```
ID  Formula
1   1+3
2   2+2*8

T1_ID   Result
1       4
2       18
```

Comment: I have described are working correctly PROCEDURE.
But how can I run in the trigger ? or How do I write function ?

Comment: I guess you have some table, and want to pass some data in that table, and part of that data need to be counted like in your SP. Give a details, elseway it is hard to describe how you can use this SP in your trigger. And no, function wont help, this could be done only by SP.

Comment: Does temp assignment results in a table!

Comment: Don't understand your last comment. Please, elaborate about trigger, what should this trigger do? What table do you have, its structure?

Comment: Trigger is created over some table and is used to do something on some interaction with table. Like after insert trigger fires when something is inserted in the table.

Comment: I have a trigger when you add data to the table. I have been going to another table when data is added cycle. and I have been a mathematical character. for example '(100-50) * 3'. Then I insert to another table as a result. But I can not run through each other automatically trigger different mathematical expressions occurring as described above.

Comment: I want to be counted in a text that trigger. MY result: '(100-50) * 3' is 150

Answer (score 0):

image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1PbU.png)

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Calculate]
    ( @expression AS VARCHAR(MAX) 
    )
    RETURNS xml
    AS
    BEGIN
      -- routine body goes here, e.g.
      -- SELECT 'Navicat for SQL Server'
    DECLARE @result xml
    declare @x xml=''
    --I can not pass as a parameter
    select @result=@x.query(('(4*3)*5-10')) 

    return   @result; 


END
```

i call this function:

```
  SELECT  CAST(CAST(CAST(dbo.[Calculate]('How do I pass parameters') AS XML) AS VARCHAR(100)) AS DECIMAL(4,2))
```

Output:

**50.00**

```
select  @result=@x.query('sql:variable("@expression")')
```

> result: '2+2' :(((

Comment: You can pass variable to xml.query, but it will not count your formula. .query('2*2') will show 4, @v = '2+2' .query(@v) will output '2+2'

Comment: Msg 8172, Level 16, State 1, Procedure Calculate, Line 14 [Batch Start Line 7]
The argument 1 of the XML data type method "query" must be a string literal.

Comment: your solutions not crated table: [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Column, parameter, or variable #1: Cannot find data type FormulaResults.
42000 - [SQL Server]Must declare the table variable "@TVP".
01000 - [SQL Server]Parameter or variable '@TVP' has an invalid data type.

Comment: Have you run the part of my batch that creates a type? I have tested this code, it executes fine.